Failing while trying to deploy ETH SAFE on BASE. What am I missing?
I tried following the steps outlined here:
https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40812-i-sent-assets-to-a-safe-address-on-the-wrong-network-any-chance-to-recover
https://share.zight.com/z8uBKZYr
This is the safe address on ETH and I am trying to deploy the same safe on BASE to recover some funds mistakenly sent to that address.
SAFE on ETH: 0xb5a701cC75bc16c1f9c36907A9b458a209E238Ad
Creation transaction for SAFE on ETH: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x74296e15cac24cfba2d7d5cc21a07779d33efa243b7acc40d3eb4da31a243d78
Using the wallet that created the safe + copying the hexdata from the transaction above and trying to send that to the proxy factory address on BASE (
0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2) fails as shown here: https://basescan.org/tx/0x07e410570023d6783da015911aaa0317db6413b95c7b8c6fd62ab1799c9f5d31
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

it looks like your safe was successfully deployed! You can check it here: https://basescan.org/address/0xb5a701cc75bc16c1f9c36907a9b458a209e238ad#code
Best, Louis
